# cPanel - How to control permission of files so only I can show them, but they cannot directly go to it?

Tags: .htaccess, permissions, cpanel

Say I have a folder `/images`. Is there a way to limit access to the folder, so that if someone goes to `/images/myImage.png`, they cannot view it, but if I can still display the image on my site, i.e. `<img src='/images/myImage.png' />` still shows on website?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, one way would be verifying `%{HTTP_REFERER}` and only allow those with valid refer to view images however this is not a bulletproof method.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/images [NC]
RewriteRule ^ / [R=301,L]
```

The above rule would verify if the image does not have a referrer from your domain, and the path starts with images, if that is the case it redirects to your domain home page.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very good at this stuff. Does this go in your .htaccess page?

Comment: @user834045 yes that should be wrote inside the `.htaccess` file and placed inside the `public_html` folder and you need to of course replace `yourdomain.com` with your domain name. I have also updated the above rule so it works with and without www on your domain name.